# In EF Code First is it possible to encapsulate properties that should be persisted to the data store?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, encapsulation, code-first

So let's say I've got a POCO that I want EF Code First to persist to a data store:

```
public class Campaign
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double GoalAmount { get; set; }
    private double AmountRaised { get; set; }
    public bool GoalMet
    {
        get
        {
            return AmountRaised >= GoalAmount;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, for whatever reason, I don't want the `AmountRaised` property to be accessible outside the object, but I *do* want it persisted to the data store. Is this possible with EF Code First?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it `internal` and make sure that the project that contains the POCOs / domain objects are in the same assembly as your `DbContext` classes.  Or you can declare "friend" assemblies in the files that contain your POCOs:

`[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyOther.Assembly")]`

Comment: Not sure if your answer is the right one, but I didn't know about InternalsVisibleTo -- great to know!

Comment: Thank you. I completely forgot about the Internal keyword. I already segregate my model into its own project, so this is perfect.